# Is it possible to make Antlr4 generate lexer from base grammar lexer instead of gener Lexer?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have `lexer grammar` called `BasicTokens` which is set of basic tokens for my language, having tokens like `null`, `true`, `false` etc.

Now when I create parser grammar say `BasicGrammar` which imports refers `BasicTokens` and another grammar called `InheritedGrammar` which imports `BasicGrammar`.

When Antlr4 generates the parser for `InheritedGrammar` it included all the rules already defined in `BasicGrammar`.

Is there a way to make Antlr describe only the rules generated in `InheritedGrammar` and not in `BasicGrammar` and also inherit `BasicGrammarParser` instead of `Parser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible due to the way ANTLR 4 implements imports.

If grammar `x` imports grammar `y`, the operation behaves as follows:

1. Load grammar `y` (and all its rules).
2. Add the rules from grammar `x` to the collection of rules. If any name collision occurs, replace the rule found in `y` with the one found in `x`.

By the time you reach the code generator, the rules hierarchy is completely flattened.

Comment: Is there a way to reference the grammar `y` without importing it?