# Generating modular ANTLR Java

Tags: java, antlr4

I have an ANTLR grammar consisting of a number of sub-items.  The high-level grammar looks something like this:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

import MyLocation, MyName, MyTime;

composite
  : myname (WS+ mylocation)? (WS+ mytime)?
```

I compile `MyGrammar.g4` to obtain the required Java code and all is well when parsing items such as `John at 4:30pm`.  However, I now have a situation where I need to parse times separately from the composite item, for example `4:30pm`.

At the moment it appears that I have to duplicate code in `MyGrammarListener` and `MyTimeListener` to handle times.  Is there any way instead in which I can tell `MyGrammarListener` to hand off to `MyTimeListener` when it sees a `mytime` so that I can avoid code duplication, or should I be handling this in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is no, you cannot do this (as of ANTLR 4.4 at least). See my answer here:

[Is it possible to make Antlr4 generate lexer from base grammar lexer instead of gener Lexer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539575/is-it-possible-to-make-antlr4-generate-lexer-from-base-grammar-lexer-instead-of/25539968#25539968)